# Uncaught Reference Error using Live Server through Visual Studio and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2010

I've been using HTML Javascript and I'm using Live server through node and this is what I get on the console.

[image: Uncaught Reference Errors On console]

Just in case you want to see my codes of HTML and JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Developer Skills & Editor Setup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background: linear-gradient(to top left, #28b487, #7dd56f);
      }
      h1 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Developer Skills & Editor Setup‍♀️</h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JS.

```
'use strict';

console.log('Hello World');
```

This is the first error

```
xx.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: AbstractProvider is not defined
    at xx.js:1
(anonymous) @ xx.js:1




const XXProvider=class extends AbstractProvider{search(){$("video").not("."+INIT_CLASS).each((a,b)=>{const c=$(b),d=b.src;if(!d)return c.addClass(INIT_CLASS),console.warn("empty src!",b);const e=new URL(d),f=/.mp4$/.test(e.pathname);return f?void(!this.ids[d]&&this.addVideo(d,c.parent()),c.addClass(INIT_CLASS)):(c.addClass(INIT_CLASS),console.warn("not mp4!",b))})}getVideoData(a,b){const c=Date.now().toString();b({vid:a,title:c,provider:"xx",variants:[{url:a,quality:"720"}]})}};
```

This is the second error

```
class Content{constructor(){this.pr=null,this.initProvider(),this.initRuntimeListener()}initProvider(){location.href.includes("facebook.com")?this.pr=new FBProvider:location.href.includes("vk.com")?this.pr=new VKProvider:location.href.includes("vimeo.com")?this.pr=new VMProvider:location.href.includes("dailymotion.com")?this.pr=new DMProvider:location.href.includes("instagram.com")?this.pr=new INProvider:location.href.includes("twitter.com")?this.pr=new TWProvider:location.href.includes("youtube.com")?(this.pr=null,chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:"setBadgeDisabled"})):this.pr=new XXProvider,this.pr&&this.pr.run()}initRuntimeListener(){chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((a,b,c)=>{"getVideo"===a.action&&this.pr&&c(this.pr.videos)})}}let downloadQuery=new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("isdowloadquery");window.self!==window.top||downloadQuery||(window.onload=function(){new Content});
```

Comment: Please provide the full Javascript code which is there in the image.

Comment: restart your browser, it should work fine, if you dont own `xx.js`

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a project which was in laravel. I faced same error but when I hover on the error I saw it says chrome extension. So I disable the extension. Also when I open the link of site in incognito tab it was working, no error in incognito but in other window, there was error and it was because of chrome extension. Try changing the access of all extensions from all sites to when you click on extension.[image]

Answer (score -1):

You haven't given *'AbstractProvider'* variable any value. Please share the full javascript code in your question, or it will be very difficult to answer it. According to the code you have provided in the question, there shouldn't be any problems like that.

**Try: Adding < script > tag outside of the body element (Under it).**

Comment: Ive tried adding the <script> tag outside the body element. Its not working.

Comment: Hey im just gonna hide the reference error since I can see now the output. Or should I? Lmao.

Comment: I have no idea how server's code works, so I can't help you out on that.